# JavaScript can't access JSON value using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I can't access any values in my parsed JSON via their keys of which all are valid JSON; here's my code:

I'm operating on `JSON.parse` data using both syntaxes to get the values yet none of them are working:

```js
let json

module.exports.checkLoggedIn = async () => {
  json = fs.readFileSync(configPath, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } else {
      return JSON.parse(data)
    }
  })

  console.log(json)
  console.log(json.id)
  console.log(json["id"])

  return true ? json.loggedIn == true : false 
}
```

The first `console.log` prints the JSON of the file, but the next two logging attempts print `undefined`.

Also I'm using Node.js which is what the `fs` module is, but the `JSON` module which is the concern of this post is native to JavaScript.

Comment: The `fs.readfilesync` function does not accept a callback so your JSON.parse is never executed.

Comment: And a node callback of the  `func (err,data)` kind expects the call back function to completely handle the side effects of its arguments - any value explicitly returned from the callback is discarded. Specifically `return JSON.parse(data)` would go nowhere even if the callback were processed.

Comment: how about ... `const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configPath, { encoding: 'utf8' }));`?